# How to set up vitest unit test __mocks__ for an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, vitest

There's a module `get-data-wrapper.ts`, where I'd like to mock an async remote call that happens in there, but I'm not sure how to do it using Vitest. Coming from traditional OOP languages, I'm a bit confused how this works.

I have `./get-data-wrapper.ts` that gets some remote data:

```
import { getRemoteData } from './get-remote-data.ts';


export getDataWrapper = async() {
  ...
  return await getRemoteData(); <-- Would like to mock this
}
```

`./get-remote-data.ts`:

```
export async function getData() {
   // Makes an API call to get remote data
}
```

My test looks like this:

`./get-data-wrapper.specs.ts`:

```
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest';
import { getRemoteData } from '../__mocks__/get-remote-data.ts';

describe('get remote data', () => {
  test('returns data', async () => {

    getRemoteImage.mockResolvedValueOnce(expectedData); <-- Unsure if getRemoteImage is the same instance injectted into get-data-wrapper.ts

    const result = await getDataWrapper();

    expect(result).toBe(exectedData); <-- Would like to achieve this
  });
});
```

1. What should my `__mocks__` file look like for `getRemoteData` to pass this test?
2. The other thing I'm not sure is if `getRemoteImage` imported here is the same instance that's injected into get-data-wrapper.ts for this test. If not, how do I set resolved data for it?